# Run Mediawiki on a W7 Workstation

Tags: apache-http-server, mediawiki

Is is possible to run and use Media Wiki, on a workstation ? 
I'm guessing this involves running Apache on the the same machine.

I'm not very familiar with Apache or Media Wiki or server side software in general.

Cheers.

Comment: Do you specifically need MediaWiki, or you just wanted a Wiki page that you can put data in? If you just want a wiki that is usable, check this page for [DokuWiki on a Stick](http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2008-05/16-dokuwiki_on_a_stick_2008-05-05) If you specifically want MediaWiki, you can try to follow the [Running MediaWiki on Windows](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Windows). And to answer your first question, Yes MediaWiki can be run on any workstation (including Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [MediaWiki](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/mediawiki.aspx) on Windows via the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/).   The installer should guide you through all the steps to install MediaWiki on your Windows Workstation.

Comment: My sys-ad said he'll get one running for me on a server. But your solution looks like what i asked for. Thanks for that. I may end up trying if the wiki never shows up being a low priority...